# como hacer la diferencia en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo la **Tabla A:**

```
-------------------
*    fechaA       *
-------------------
* 2017-09-01      *
* 2017-09-02      *
* 2017-09-03      *
* 2017-09-04      *
* 2017-09-05      *
* 2017-09-06      *
* 2017-09-07      *
* 2017-09-08      *
* 2017-09-09      *
* 2017-09-10      *
-------------------
```

Y la **Tabla B**

```
-------------------
*    fechaB       *
-------------------
* 2017-09-01      *
* 2017-09-06      *
* 2017-09-10      *
-------------------
```

Lo que necesito es la diferencia de **A** en **B**

El **Resultado seria**

```
-------------------
*    Resultado    *
-------------------
* 2017-09-02      *
* 2017-09-03      *
* 2017-09-04      *
* 2017-09-05      *
* 2017-09-07      *
* 2017-09-08      *
* 2017-09-09      *
-------------------
```

> El problema es que no se como hacerlo intente con `fechaA!=FechaB` pero aun asi el resultado es toda la tabla **A**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has probado con un not in?

algo asi como:

```
SELECT fechaA       
FROM TABLA_A
WHERE fechaA NOT IN (SELECT FechaB FROM TABLA_B)
```

Esto lo que hace es buscar los igualar las fechas que estan en A, con las que no figuran en B, entonces solo trae esas.

Comment: Bien!!! me funciono de maravilla, gracias